# reverse one to many transformation in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataset like

```
a1<tab>b1,b2,b3,b4
a2<tab>b1,b2,b3
........
........
........
aN<tab>bX,bY,bZ
```

I want to transform the same into reverse fashion i.e

```
    b1 -> a1
    b1 -> aY
....
....
    b2 -> aX
    b2 -> aY
    b2 -> aZ
....
....
    bN -> a1
    bN -> aY
```

How to achieve the same without clogging heap space?

I have used mapPartitions to do partition wise transformations to avoid shuffle and then use distcp to merge by key. But when the number of values for one key is high in number, the spark jobs seem to fail.

relevant code snippet is below :

```
val res_rdd=rdd.mapPartitions{
      iterator => {
                    iterator.toList
                      .map(f => (f.split("\t")(1).split(","),f.split("\t")(0))).flatMap(k => k._1.map(y=> (y,k._2)))
                      .iterator
                   }
    }


    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val df=res_rdd.toDF("newKey","newValue")
    df.write.partitionBy("newKey").text(outputPath)
```

The end result needs to have all the "newValue"s per "newKey" file.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't convert to `List`
      iterator.toList

No reason to keep everything in memory.

There is no gain from `mapPartitions` and it would be better to use `Dataset` all the way:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv(path).toDF("key", "value")
  .withColumn("value", explode(split(col("value"), ",")))
```

Comment: actually I have to group the values as well by the "newKey". Basically, in the end, i need one file per "newKey" with all the "newValue"s in that line by line.
without mapPartitions, the shuffle is very high.

Comment: also, as i tried like you mentioned, while writing the resulting dataframe as 
df.write.partitionBy("value").text(outputPath), many tasks failed after a while and when trying to re-attempt it gave file already written as some of the data had already been written.

Comment: How to effectively write the transformed dataframe without failing now that the transformation part is fine.